# Every np-complete problem reduces to the Halting problem. Is this true?

Tags: np-complete, np-hard, halting-problem

I guess that every np-complete problem reduces to the np-hard problem, so the given statement is true. But don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Halting problem is not NP-hard. It is unsolvable.

Comment: Every problem in NP reduces to every NP-hard problem, and a problem is NP-complete if it's in NP and it's NP-hard.  You don't prove those things. Those are the *definitions* of NP-complete and NP-hard.  You *could* reduce every NP-complete problem to halting, but why?